# Pyspark Logistic Regression model changing accuracy after saving

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I  built a Pyspark Multinomial Logistic Regression model and integrated it with a Django web app so that I make predictions on the querysets. On my model, I saved it using the recommended

```
temp_path = pjoin("/home/maffsojah/Projects/HIT_400/capstone_project/web/tbank/spark-warehouse")
reg_path = temp_path + '/reg'
reg.save(reg_path)
model2 = LogisticRegression.load(reg_path)
model2.getMaxIter()

model_path = temp_path + '/reg_model'
regModel.save(model_path)
model2 = LogisticRegressionModel.load(model_path)
```

When I test inside my model, eveything will be working fine and the accuracy is **92%** but when I save and load my model inside my django app, the accuracy becomes very low and approximately **22%**.

How do I save and load my model while maintaining the same accuracy levels and parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do Logistic Regression, you will end up with some weights that don't change when you save it. Also in terms accuracy, not sure if you understand the concept of Machine Learning but the input is data. I think you probably used a different data as input for your django app and then of course it can happen that your accuracy is low. There is no way to maintain the same accuracy levels except if you use the same dataset that you trained your model on but that is called overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I was confused on the accuracy part. So even if the model had high accuracy with Training and testing data, is it possible that it will not make correct predictions with new data? In my django app, I only intended to predict only

Comment: Yes. It will only make correct prediction if the training and test datasets are representative of the new data. For example, if you try to predict the height of a person based on certain parameters, but your training and test dataset only contains data for males, your accuracy might go down when predicting height for females.

Comment: @maffsojah Jaco gave a very good explanation. If you want to have a higher accuracy you should collect more data and train your model on more data. Your model will improve for free as long as the data allows this. Otherwise you should try it with more complex models like Random Forest. By the way this is not a PySpark questions but related to machine learning in general.

Comment: thank you, I will start reading more into more complex models